# Calculating an average with the result of a group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains two tables.

borrower table

```
BorrowID | ClientID | BookID
```

client table

```
ClientID | Occupation
```

The ClientID in borrower table is the foreign key.

I am trying to get the average number of borrowed books by Occupation.  I am able to get the number of people per occupation with this query:

```
SELECT count(Occupation) as occupation_count, Occupation
FROM client
GROUP BY Occupation
```

I can also get the number of books per occupation with this query:

```
SELECT client.Occupation, count(borrower.ClientID) AS books_per_occupation
FROM client
LEFT JOIN borrower
ON (borrower.ClientID=client.ClientID)
GROUP BY client.Occupation
```

The issue is that I cannot divide the books_per_occupation by the occupation_count.
It seems a sub-query would be the way, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of books per client by occupation.  If so, you can use a single query and `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT c.Occupation, count(b.ClientId) / count(distinct c.clientId) AS books_per_client
FROM client c LEFT JOIN
     borrower b
     ON b.ClientID = c.ClientID
GROUP BY c.Occupation;
```